# Primer registro de un foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Buenos dias compañeros necesito saber como puedo identificar cuando se crea el primer registro de una relacion, tengo 2 tablas relacionadas la tabla principal tiene como llave primaria idclase y la segunda tabla con su foreign key idclase y llave primaria idprueba
yo tengo una clase llamada ciencias que se creo el 12/04/2017 y el primer programa de esa clase se creo el 15/05/2017 esa fecha se tiene que poner automaticamente en la columna primer programa de la clase de ciencias

```
create table clase(
idclase int identity primary key,
clase varchar(10),
fechaclase datetime ,
primerprograma datetime
)


create table programa(
idclase int ,
idprograma int identity primary key,
programa varchar(20),
fechaprograma datetime,
)

alter table programa add constraint idclase
foreign key(idclase) references clase(idclase)
go

IDCLASE     IDPROGRAMA      CLASE       PROGRAMA        FECHACLASE      FECHAPROGRAMA   PRIMERPROGRAMA
1                           CIENCIAS                    12/04/2017                      ***15/05/2017***
2                           TECNOLOGIA                  22/04/17
3                           ARTES                       26/07/17                        ***25/04/2017***
1           1               CIENCIAS    QUMICA                          ***15/05/2017***        
3           2               ARTES       ARTESNIAS                       ***25/04/2017***
```

Lo que hago es un trigger para que se vaya guardando un tipo historial para que al final toda esa informacion se guarde en otra tabla que se llama movimientosfechas

Comment: no hay forma de hacerlo a menos que tengas una columna con la fecha de inserción de la fila en la segunda tabla (o una tabla con la historia de cambios)

Comment: para esto vamos a necesitar que describas las tablas, un grafico de relacion seria ideal, y que nos digas a que consideras el primer registro de la segunda tabla

Comment: me refiero que si en la primer tabla tengo un idclase =1425, el primer registro de la segunda tabla es en el que se uso un por primera vez idclase =1425

Comment: el primer registro ingresado? mira el comentario de @Lamak. guardas fechas en algun lado de eso?

Comment: Ya puse un ejemplo compañero al final lo que quiero al conocer el primer registro es actualizar las fechas automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Select top 1 * from programa where idclase=1425 order by idprograma

Si id programa es autonumerico te debe retornar el primero.

Comment: Pero para todos los casos compañero tal vez no me estoy explicando bien, yo tengo una clase llamada ciencias  que se creo el 12/04/2017 y el primer programa de esa clase se creo el 15/05/2017 esa fecha se tiene que poner automaticamente en la columna primer programa de la tabla clase

Answer (score 0):

Debería  crear una columna que almacene la fecha  y la hora en la que se crea el registro, puedes hacer un select Top 1 fechaRegistro from programa   where programa.idclase =@clase.idclase.

Comment: Es un datetime compañero las fechas